# OSGI gogo console in JBoss?

Tags: jboss, osgi, apache-felix, jboss-4.2.x

Fyi, I am using Maven and Eclipse 3.6

Is it possible to deploy "felix" to JBoss (4.2.3) - such that I could access the Gogo shell from my Eclipse console?

If so - what kind of "descriptor" should I use? I've only ever encountered the "servlet" type deployments, with **web.xml** file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: I've been working on this exact issue, Felix inside JBoss 4.2.3.GA, I will link some code here by the weekend.  What is currently working; gogo shell configadmin and felix file install.  Not working; LogService or PAX Logging.  What it does is register OSGi services whose canonical name match pattern property as JBoss MBeans and the other way it creates proxies from JBoss services (whose canonical name matches a pattern property)

Comment: That sounds great. I don't even need them to be registered as services in jboss - as long as I have some way to run and control the OSGI container - I am happy. Sadly - this is the point I got stuck on, and there is very little help/expertise in my location for anything OSGI.